# Tab Content not showing on FragmentTabHost Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I have tried using FragmentTabHost. all went well, and has managed to show the tab well. but my fragment not showing layout of that class. I've tried using the TextView, but still did not appear.
please help me.

My FragmentActivity

```
public class ViewDetailAnak extends FragmentActivity{

private static String idanak;

private FragmentTabHost tabHost;
private static final String TRANS_SPEC = "";
private static final String US_SPEC = "";
private static final String TABU_SPEC =  "";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fro_single_item_anak);


      tabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
      tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(),android.R.id.tabcontent);

        tabHost.addTab(
                tabHost.newTabSpec(TRANS_SPEC)
                .setIndicator(TRANS_SPEC, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_trans)),
                FROVDATransaksi.class, null);
        tabHost.addTab(
                tabHost.newTabSpec(US_SPEC)
                .setIndicator(US_SPEC, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_us)),
                FROVDAUangsaku.class, null);
        tabHost.addTab(
                tabHost.newTabSpec(TABU_SPEC)
                .setIndicator(TABU_SPEC, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_tab)),
                FROVDATabungan.class, null);
}
```

One of 3 fragment

```
 public static class FROVDAUangsaku extends Fragment {
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 }

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fro_vda_uangsaku, container, false);
     return v;


}
   }
```

and this is XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:paddingTop="15dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/user1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="15.86"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtNama_FRO_Profil"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="@color/nama" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/txNama_fra_profil"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                                android:text="Uang Saku"
                                android:textColor="#666666"
                                android:textSize="9dp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/txtJumlahAnak_FRO_Profil"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:textSize="12dp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/txtnomuangsaku"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                                android:text="Tabungan"
                                android:textColor="#666666"
                                android:textSize="9sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/saldotabungan"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:textSize="12dp" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical" >

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/btnLogoutFRO_profilo"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="Edit Profile"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

      <View
          android:layout_height="2dip"
          android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
          android:background="#666666" />

</TableLayout>
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="38dp" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

ignore inside TableLayout. The only design. and I make fragmenttab under TableLayout